# Why is the QuerySet not updating after save in django shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-shell

So today , when i was learning Django shell interface for Database , i faced a very strange issue.

I couldn't get the updated the data even after doing the save method .

I searched about this issue, but in all those queries, they where missing save method.

Is this some django update issue or Am i Missing something?

```
>>> from hello.models import user
>>> user.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> user1 =  user("rins","rins@gmail.com","9995584433","2000-01-01")
>>> user1.save
<bound method Model.save of <user: rins@gmail.com>>
>>> user.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

So this is the output. as you can see the user objects is still blank even after saving

And this is my model

```
class user(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=11)
    dob=models.DateField()
```

Comment: You did not *call* the method. You should *call* `.save()`, (so with parenthesis).

Comment: Furthermore you should not use positional arguments, especially since the first one is normally the hidden `id`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this is what my teacher taught today :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes here:

1. You did not *call* the method. You should *call* `.save()`, (so with parenthesis); and
2. you should not use *positional arguments*, especially since the first one is normally the hidden `id`.

In the session, you thus can write this as:

```
user1 = user(name='rins',email='rins@gmail.com',phone='9995584433',dob='2000-01-01')
user1.save()
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`user`</s> to `User`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i should inform this to the professor & let my classmates know this.

Comment: user1.save - was it working on the previous versions ? because if it is , then probably i shouldn't tell the teachers that they were wrong

Comment: @SandrinJoy: no, at least not since 1.8, when I started working with Django, and this is not supported anymore since april 2018.